# How to get alert to display using javascript after draggin?

Tags: javascript

I have the below javascript.  The draggable portion of the code works, but the alert for some reason isn't working.  Any advice on how to fix it to get the alert to display?

```
 <script src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>

<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jsapi" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.3.2.min" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min" %>
   <script type="text/javascript">
  // When the document is ready set up our sortable with it's inherant function(s)
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#test-list").sortable({
      handle : '.handle',
      update : function () {
        var order = $('#test-list').sortable('serialize');
      }

    });
      });
  </script>
  <script>

   $(function(){
       $('#test1').on('click',function(){
          alert('test');
          // CONCATENATE TEXT
          // user = $('.user:nth-child(1)').text()+ ','+ $('.user:nth-child(2)').text();
          // alert(user);
          // $('#personalassessment_set3').val(user);
       });
   });
```

```
<input id="test1" type="button" value="Set Value" />
```

Comment: jQuery UI sortable method does not accept functions like that. Take your alert outside that method.

Comment: Place the alert inside the update function or take it out of the sortable function, otherwise it's a syntax error

Comment: Got it, thanks.  What about for the second function.  Where I'm trying to get an alert to display after click.  This alert isn't displaying after I click on the submit button with id test1.

Comment: @sharataka Hmm, your second alert works fine for me here too - http://jsfiddle.net/PXFU3/

Comment: y don't u create a test on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: I've removed alert from the sortable part of the js.  Now I'm just trying to get the alert to show on click, which isn't happening.

Comment: @sharataka You are using an older version of jQuery - `on()` is quite new. Replace the word `on` with `delegate`, or with `live` instead.

Comment: Is there a newer version of jquery I should use that will support both the sortable method and on()?

Comment: @sharataka Yes, get the latest version of jQuery and sortable should still work fine.